# sed or grep to read between a set of parentheses

Tags: bash, sed, command-line-interface

I'm trying to read a version number from between a set of parentheses, from this output of some command:

```
Test Application version 1.3.5

card 0: A version 0x1010000 (1.0.0), 20 ch

Total known cards: 1
```

What I'm looking to get is 1.0.0.
I've tried variations of sed and grep:

```
command.sh | grep -o -P '(?<="(").*(?=")")'

command.sh | sed -e 's/(\(.*\))/\1/'
```

and plenty of variations. No luck :-(

Help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there! In pgrep, use backslashes to keep literal meaning of parentheses, not double quotes:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
```

Comment: Riiiight..! I hate it when I miss these little things. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Having GNU grep you can also use the `\K` escape sequence available in *perl mode*:

```
grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+'
```

`\K` removes what has been matched so far. In this case the starting `(` gets removed from match.

Alternatively you could use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[()]' 'NF>1{print $2}'
```

The command splits input lines using parentheses as delimiters. Once a line has been splitted into multiple fields (meaning the parentheses were found) the version number is the second field and gets printed.

---

Btw, the `sed` command you've shown should be:

```
sed -ne 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of variations that will work. First with `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep '(' filename | sed 's/^.*[(]\(.*\)[)].*$/\1/'
```

or with a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r line; do
    value=$(expr "$line" : ".*(\(.*\)).*")
    if [ "x$value" != "x" ]; then 
        printf "%s\n" "$value"
    fi
done <"$1"
```

Both return `1.0.0` for your given input file.

Comment: The `grep` can rather easily be factored out. Just change the `sed` to only print when the substitution was successful: `sed -n 's/.*(\([^()]*\)).*/\1/p' filename`

Comment: Yes, I found that out from hek2mgl's suppression of printing pattern space. That's one for the sed toolbox. Thanks.